# Rake Not Creating Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, migrate, dbmigrate

**Problem**

`rake db:migrate` is not creating tables in my MySQL database. (Yes, I have read all similar posts, and implemented their suggestions, please continue reading.)

**Code**

database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: asreport
```

Line from gemfile (yes, I already gem install'd it too):

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
```

/appfile/db/migrate/create_users.rb (I've also tried making the second line 'def up'):

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :password
      t.integer :usertype
      t.string :salt
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

After I run `rake db:drop`, `rake db:create` to refresh, rake db:migrate --trace reads (after this output, 'show tables' in mysql still only shows schema_migrations):

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

**What I've Tried**

First of all, I know that I am connecting to MySQL via Ruby, as `db:drop` create does indeed create the database itself, just not the table.

I've read all the relevant stack overflow posts I could find on the issue. I've tried rollback, dropping my database directly on SQL, and `db:drop/create`.

I've tried deleting and recreating my migration script too.

I've run db:migrate multiple times (by itself and after `db:drop/create's, rollback's, resets)`, but the schema_migrations always has 0 entries and my `schema.rb` file is on `version: 0`.

Comment: What does it  do when run Rake db:migrate ?  like does it do nothing , say something , errors out

Comment: Do you know if the user you are connecting with has privileges to create tables

Comment: I see you are root ,

Comment: Yup, I used root to make sure privileges weren't an issue. Also, as a sanity check, I just tried creating a table as root directly in MySQL, with no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not following the naming conventions outlined in the [Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Specifically, this:

> **2.1** 
>   Creating a Standalone Migration Migrations are stored as files in the db/migrate directory, one for each migration class. The name of
>   the file is of the form YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_create_products.rb, that is to
>   say a UTC timestamp identifying the migration followed by an
>   underscore followed by the name of the migration. The name of the
>   migration class (CamelCased version) should match the latter part of
>   the file name. For example 20080906120000_create_products.rb should
>   define class CreateProducts and
>   20080906120001_add_details_to_products.rb should define
>   AddDetailsToProducts. Rails uses this timestamp to determine which
>   migration should be run and in what order, so if you're copying a
>   migration from another application or generate a file yourself, be
>   aware of its position in the order.

Go ahead and try a dummy migration to see the file name convention.

```
$ bin/rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts part_number:string
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks so much!